# Run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)' The index into the specified collection is out of bounds

Tags: vba, checkbox

I am running periodically into an error:
Run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)'
The index into the specified collection is out of bounds.

This error is thrown on the line

> For Each cb In wks.Shapes

Here is the full code:

```
Sub SelectAll(wks As Worksheet)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cb As Shape

'Loop through Checkboxes
  For Each cb In wks.Shapes
    If cb.Type = msoFormControl Then
      If cb.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
        cb.OLEFormat.Object.Value = xlOn
        With cb.OLEFormat.Object
            Application.Run .OnAction, .Name
        End With
      End If
    End If
  Next cb
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```