# Out of bounds error on for each sh in ws.Shapes statement

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have the following sub which is supposed to loop through all the shapes in a sheet and do something:

```
Private Sub plasser_knappar(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim sh As Shape

    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
        Debug.Print "Do stuff"
    Next sh
End Sub
```

However, on one of my sheets I get an error when the code reaches the line `For Each sh in ws.Shapes` - *"Run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009) The index into the specified collection is out of bounds"*. This error *does not happen* in other worksheets in the workbook. Can anyone shed some light on what might be the problem here?

Comment: Can you delete the sheet and make it again? It seems like the sheet is somehow corrupted.

Comment: This [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912369/run-time-error-2147352567-80020009-the-index-into-the-specified-collection) is for the same, still, no  answer as well.

Comment: Is this - https://pastebin.com/NpLadmpA - giving the same error for that worksheet? Then consider using as less code as possible to replicate the issue in your question.

Comment: @Vityata It does, and seeing the info funthomas added in his answer, coupled with the fact that I don't get the same error in other sheets in the workbook, I am gonna assume it is indeed a matter of the worksheet having got corrupted somehow.

Comment: Does the parsed ws have any shapes on it?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Yes, several - I don't think that *should* influence it though

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/343f9520-fb3f-4660-aace-8f8dddadaf2c/the-index-into-the-specified-collection-is-out-of-bounds?forum=vsto) about this error code and it seems that this was caused by an corrupt workbook.